# Android not receiving push notifications from Firebase with FCM registration token

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have the code that will show the push notification when the Android app receives it. My code is able to send push notifications to all devices except for one. I have also tried sending notifications manually using this link:
https://console.firebase.google.com/project/projname-fface/notification/compose

I used the FCM registration token generated by FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken() this method.

Only one device is not able to receive this push notification. Is this registration token corrupted? How would this device be able to receive push notification?

I am trying this using two ways.

1. Using PHP Code as follows:

   // Open connection
   $ch = curl_init();
   // set the url and post variables

   // Execute this post
   $result = curl_exec($ch);

   I get success back like this:

{"multicast_id":8822218177628709204,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1488169759724709%6ab45a43f9fd7ecd"}]}

2. Using Firebase Dashboard.

Please see the attached screenshot. I just do a simple "send a message" to a single device. The status on Firebase dashboard says "Completed". But this device never received any notification.
[image]

I apologize if the information still isn't clear. I am just trying to figure out why this one android phone doesn't receive notifications anymore.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why downvote? I am really stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ***not** the downvoter* -- Hi. It's hard to tell what's wrong. The only thing we know is that *it doesn't work for a specific device*. Are there any error messages after you send the message? Can you provide the relevant code snippets? A sample payload. How are you sending the messages originally?

Comment: @AL. Thank you for the response. I have updated my question a little bit.
Here is the response I receive from my curl post execution:
$result = curl_exec($ch);
Response:
{"multicast_id":8822218177628709204,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1488169759724709%6ab45a43f9fd7ecd"}]}

And this user still doesn't receive any notification. Could there be something in his phone setting?

Comment: Possibly device specific. Is it Xiaomi?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your device has Google Play Store installed. If it's an emulator, make sure its Android version includes "Google APIs" (notifications won't work without it).

Comment: This device has Google Play Store installed. He used to receive notifications and I am not sure what happened now that he stopped receiving them.

Comment: Because Google Play Store is required by FCM (and first version of the question didn't mention that it used to work on that device).